# RHEL 6.6: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"

Tags: linux, proxy, yum, rhel6

First of all, it's the first time I setup RHEL machines, I'm more used to Debian.

We're installing many machine at the same time.
We've upgraded from RHEL 6.3 to RHEL 6.6 and we're now trying to install openmotif22 (required for an IBM installer that will come in a few days).

On the first machine, everything worked, we had no problem, but on the second one, we got this error for those 2 packages, and ... i have no idea were it comes from.

```
root@mymachine:~# yum install -y openmotif22.i686 openmotif22.x86_64 --verbose
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
Loading "product-id" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Loading "subscription-manager" plugin
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Config time: 0.260
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Looking for repo options for [main]
Looking for repo options for [rhel-x86_64-server-6]
Repo 'rhel-x86_64-server-6' setting option 'enabled' = '1'
Repo 'rhel-x86_64-server-6' setting option 'gpgcheck' = '1'
Yum Version: 3.2.29
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Install Process
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.306
Obs Init time: 0.288
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 will be installed
Checking deps for openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('rtld(GNU_HASH)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.2)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libc.so.6', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libXt.so.6', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libXp.so.6', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libXmu.so.6', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libXm.so.3', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libXext.so.6', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libX11.so.6', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libUil.so.3', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libSM.so.6', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libMrm.so.3', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('libICE.so.6', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
looking for ('/usr/share/X11/XKeysymDB', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of openmotif22.i686 0:2.2.3-19.el6 - u
Error: failed to retrieve repodata/9681fa082b2fd9fdd65a0548409bd4c16be74e217e46d11c1fff3470300e4df0-filelists.xml.gz from rhel-x86_64-server-6
       error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
```

Probably from a configuration file, but, we've filled the

`/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date`

with our proxy settings.

Our 'http_proxy' variable is empty, on both machine, and our `yum.conf` have no proxy information at all, on both machine too.
Both machine are registered with rhn_register.

I am running out of configuration files to check.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.
What did i do:

1. Fill up the rhsm.conf file with proxy settings ( `/etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf` )
2. rebooting the machine
3. try to install: `root@mymachine:~# yum install -y openmotif22.i686 openmotif22.x86_64` -> fail, same error
4. `yum clean -all -v`
5. `yum repolist -v`
6. `root@mymachine:~# yum install -y openmotif22.i686 openmotif22.x86_64` -> worked ... No idea why, but the reboot is the key.

I already had done those steps without the reboot, it didn't worked.

Comment: i dont think reboot is the key, but `yum clean all` did the trick.  There alway yum cache in `/var/cache/yum`. Removing it via `yum clean all` solved it for you.